# HaProxy tls checking CN

Tags: ssl, tcp, haproxy

I need to configure HaProxy to act as a reverse TLS proxy. I would like to check CN received from server certificate. I have several problems. First if I write this kind of configuration it's not working (assuming CN is equal to server hostname) :

```
global
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 4096
    log /dev/log local0 debug
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.1

frontend test_ft
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    bind 127.0.0.1:9001
    use_backend test_bk

backend test_bk
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    acl check_cn ssl_c_s_dn(CN) -m str remote
    tcp-request content reject unless check_cn
    server remote remote:9000 check ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/local.pem ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/rootCA.pem verify required
```

Requests are always blocked even if the server certificate contains the good CN. I have tried also :

```
    acl check_cn ssl_c_s_dn(CN) -m str remote
    use-server remote if check_cn
    server remote remote:9000 check ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/local.pem ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/rootCA.pem verify required
```

In this case, it's the opposite even if server CN is not equal to "remote", TLS connection is every time OK.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question want you to check the backend (bc) common name (cn) in haproxy.

There is no fetch method for that as you can see in the documenation [Fetching samples at Layer 5](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.4) .

Maybe this fetch method [ssl_f_s_dn](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.4-ssl_f_s_dn) will help you to solve your problem.